# requesting unique id every page load

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a page that needs to select a Unique ID for every page load. It's basically a purchase order system, but the PO will be just the UID, so it's important that no user can get the same ID. I tried doing just calling upon last ID, then adding 1 and submitting, but that could create conflict if two or more users are entering at the same time. What's the best way to pull a UID for each page load? Any solutions?

Thanks

Lloyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UniqId() is one way, but results in large numbers. As V Patel says, there's also "Auto Increment" and this is probably the option you want.

1. In MySQL set up a table (say "PurchaseOrders") with a field "po_id" and set that to be the primary key and [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). Add another field "po_status" (TinyInt*1) and another "po_lastused" (Date*1). Status will be 0=draft, 1=final, 2=shipped etc. LastUsed is the last time the user accessed the details.
2. When you want to create a new purchase order, INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders(po_status, po_lastused) VALUES(0, NOW());  Note: you've not specified the actual purchase order
3. You can get the po_id through asking for the "last insert id" (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php, depending on your coding library)
4. Store the po_id in a session variable so that when the user returns, you know their po_id(*2)
5. Each time a user access a purchase order, if "last updated" was more then 5 minutes ago, update the timer.
6. Periodically deleted all purchase orders that are draft and where last updated is older than your session (e.g. after a day)

This way, you'll end up with nice purchase order numbers that are easily quotable.

*1 For the purists, You can also use Enum for the status, and int for dates - depends on your preference. You can also set the date to be automatically updated. But I'm keeping it simple.)

*2 Again, for the purists, there is more security you could implement here to ensure the "other" users can't access someone else's purchase order, but this is enough to start.

Comment: The P.O system itself is very basic. The users will be only giving this P.O to Vendors while AT the vendors picking up their stuff. This basically is an open and close PO system. So there should be no need to keep the session open. However your code would still work I do believe just leaving out a few steps. When step 2 is activated will it prevent doubling up of PO's because of the INSERT? If two guys log on at once. The last insert id works, but if two guys log on at the same time will they not get the same ID?

Comment: No, they will never, ever get the same id. (with uniqid there is actually a small possibility of the same id if you have a load balanced system across multiple servers). If you don't need sessions then it is simpler. Much simpler as you simply use the auto increment, get the last insert id and you're done.

Comment: With lastinsert id Can I query it prior to get the PO in advance of the insert. From my knowledge of lastinsertid it's after the insert command that we insert it (or with the insert). But I would like the guys to see the PO prior to inserting. This way they can put total price on the PO right at the same time as giving the PO to the customer. Without actually completing the PO first. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense. you are correct in that you get it after the insert - this is how it guarantees it is unique. The options you have are lock the entire table to prevent inserts (which is not really an option) or to use the Fuller sedation method to essentially reserve the id by doing the insert with blank data, and then update when you have the full data. So it's back to the more complex option outlined in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`uniqid`](http://php.net/uniqid) function to get a unique key. Run it through [`hexdec`](http://php.net/hexdec) if you need an integer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has one:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 0):

Use auto increment feature of the database in use, especially if you like it to be a number and don't need it till you want to persist it.